# Fancybox issue loading certain ajax URL's in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, fancybox

I'm using fancybox throughout a website without issues but i've found a strange bug with it in Chrome - certain URL's just won't load.

The console logs the following error:

```
GET https://xxxxxxx/advertise/stats/test.asp  jquery.min.js:18
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send    jquery.min.js:18
f.extend.ajax                          jquery.min.js:18
_start                                 jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js:243
$.fn.fancybox                          jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js:819
f.event.handle                         jquery.min.js:17
f.event.add.i.handle.k                 jquery.min.js:16
```

I have checked in Fiddler and the above request doesn't trigger so it must be failing before it makes the request.

The odd thing is that if I move the stats/ directory out of the advertise/ directory and to the root it loads. See the console log:

```
XHR finished loading: "https://xxxxxxxx/stats/test.asp". jquery.min.js:18
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send    jquery.min.js:18
f.extend.ajax                          jquery.min.js:18
_start                                 jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js:243
$.fn.fancybox                          jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js:819
f.event.handle                         jquery.min.js:17
f.event.add.i.handle.k                 jquery.min.js:16
```

The above was tested in a stripped down file with the bare essentials required to run fancybox.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem. I have AdBlock plugin installed and it doesn't like the folder name 'advertise' so is blocking anything from loading that is in that folder.

Comment: any file name (including the path) that contains any string as in the AdBlock Plus easylist https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt won't be displayed (either inside or outside fancybox). See this similar post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fancybox/B2B9twBujD4 Note that is not a fancybox or OS or Browser specific issue.